# Create a horizontal list to select age

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to build something like this[image: age selection]

I'm doing it in React Native, what you would recommend me to use to create a list like this that I could increase the on focus number?

Comment: Look for react native carousel libraries.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple version of what you want.

```
const App = () => {

const ages = new Array(100).fill(0);

return <FlatList
 data={ages}
 horizontal
 renderItem={({index}) => <View style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}><Text>{index + 1}</Text></View>}
/>

}
```